# Spring security login on Db not working and now giving any error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

after studying Spring security login with username and password set inside the security-config file, I'm trying to study a login system to query a DB.

The login system is not working. My problem is that I just get the message "Bad credentials"; I don't get any other kind of error that helps me to understand the problem, even if I try to query a DB that doens't exist; so, I'm not able to understand what I'm doing wrong, because I don't get any error message.

This is my security-config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

     <http use-expressions="true">

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login"         
            default-target-url="/prv/sottoPassword" 
            always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
            username-parameter="j_username"
            password-parameter="j_password" />

        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?out=1" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />

      <intercept-url  pattern="/**" access="permitAll()" />
        <intercept-url  pattern="/prv/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" /> 

    </http>     

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
         <authentication-provider>

            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="select username,password from users where username=?" authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, r.authority from users u, roles r where u.userid = r.userid and u.username =?" >

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

this is my login page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>    

<form method="post"  action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />">
            ${message}
                <div class="DivLineaControllo">
                    <div class="DivLineaControlloLabel">
                            <spring:message code="label.login.utenza"/> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="DivLineaControlloInput">        
                        <input type="text" name="j_username" />
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="DivLineaControllo">
                    <div class="DivLineaControlloLabel">
                        <spring:message code="label.login.password"/>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="DivLineaControlloInput">        
                    <input type="password" name="j_password" />
                    </div>
                </div>                  

                <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: No, i did't get any error :(

Comment: Your `users-by-username-query` is wrong, it must return 3 columns (username, password, enabled). Next to that you also have no security. Your `/**` is the first in your list of secured urls, which matches everything. The order of your `intercept-url` elements is important, the first one that matches is the one that gets applied. The order of consulting is the order in which they are defined.

Comment: Thank you man. I edited the code according to your advice and now it works. What wasn't clear to me is that Spring expects me to write a query with 3 columns. Does this mean that I have to edit al my databases and added the "enabled" column??

Answer (score 0):

select 'true' AS enabled .... from User....